# How can I tell if a game is supported by Nvidia Gamestream?

Tags: nvidia-gamestream

How can I tell if a game is supported by [Nvidia Gamestream](https://support-shield.nvidia.com/gamestream-user-guide/)? Is there a comprehensive list published somewhere?

Comment: Nvidia's page https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/shield/games/ lists the union of Geforce Now, Android and Gamestream games. There doesn't appear any way to filter it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, the [Nvidia Shield page](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/shield/games/) lists games allowed by Gamestream. Although there's no way of filtering this, Gamestream games are indicated by an icon to the side.

It's not very elegant, but you can count the number of games by going to your browser console and entering the following:

```
$(".gfn-game-name").has(".shield-gamestream-support-icon").length
```

which currently gives me 631 games.

You can also do a rudimentary (and irreversible) filter with something like this:

```
$(".gfn-game-name:not(:has(.shield-gamestream-support-icon))").hide()
```

You can also enter this in your address bar by adding `javascript:` to the front, i.e.

```
javascript:$(".gfn-game-name:not(:has(.shield-gamestream-support-icon))").hide()
```

Comment: Thanks, filtering the list worked just how I wanted.